# SKSpriteNode using APNG for texture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Is it possible to use the `APGN` format as a texture for `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: Anything is possible,  but no, you cannot do it with native libraries

Comment: Maybe you know the libraries that will help me solve the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't bother even using APNG, just break that up into separate PNG and load it

Comment: This is not very suitable. There is a certain APNG with the text. In APNG, it takes 125 kilobytes, and in expanded form - 7 megabytes. The difference is too high

Comment: what are you talking about, APNG is just a bunch of PNGs in a container, where the first image is your key frame, and every image after that is a difference.  Just save in the same fashion.  Also in the end it will still decompress to 7MB in RAM so the only thing you are saving on is disk space

Comment: I understended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, No, not natively.  APNG is not a widely used format, so it is not supported.  You would need to find a 3rd library to handle APNG for you, or seperate your APNG into seperate PNG files.